# Generate a new column based on another column in the data matrix

Tags: r

I have a data like this:

```
> data
  gene log2FC
1    A     NA
2    B      1
3    C      2
4    D     -3
```

And I'd like to generate data with a new column FC based on log2FC:

```
> data
  gene log2FC FC
1    A     NA NA
2    B      1  2
3    C      2  4
4    D     -3 -8
```

I wrote a loop to get the result:

```
LFC <- data$log2FC
FC <- NULL

for ( i in 1:length(LFC) ) {

a <- LFC[i]

if ( is.na(a) ) {
  FC[i] <- NA
} else {
  if ( a < 0 ) { 
  FC[i] <- (-1)/(2^a)
} else {
  FC[i] <- 2^a
} 

}
}

data$FC <- FC
```

Could anyone let me know a more clever way to generate the data, like using apply or other function? Thank you for teaching me!

Comment: I guess `data$FC<-sign(df$log2FC)*2^abs(df$log2FC)` should work without any `if` or `ifelse` or `for` loops.

Comment: @nicola - that should be an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any loop or `if` `ifelse` and similar:

```
data$FC<-sign(df$log2FC)*2^abs(df$log2FC)
```

Comment: Thank you! That's a better solution!